# Where can I find an Eclipse External Annotations file for the JDK8?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, nullable, eclipse-jdt

I intend to work with Eclipse External Annotations. Where can I find the EEA set for the JDK8?

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis/External_Annotations

Comment: A partial EEA set seems to be here:
https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-null-eea-augments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as @jörn-guy-süß said in Comment (just posting this as an Answer you can accept), the http://www.lastnpe.org community provides EEAs for various libraries, [including some for JDK8](https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-null-eea-augments/tree/master/libraries/java/java/util).  It's not fully complete yet, but we very much welcome further contributions from you! ;-)